# How to open a new Tab with javascript and display some chart

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, javascript-objects, react-google-charts

I am trying to create a function which will open a new window tab and display a chart for a set of values. I am able to get up this but for some reason, the new tab is opening up but no data is displayed in the page. Could you please suggest where I am going wrong.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Name', 'TimeTaken'],
      ['BookMark1',  10],
      ['BookMark2',  20],
      ['BookMark3',  10],
      ['BookMark4',  20],
      ['BookMark5',  30],
      ['BookMark6',  26]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Time Taken to Apply Each Bookmark',
      vAxis: {title: 'Time_Seconds'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Bookmark_Name'},
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
    };
    var w=window.open("");
    var newNode = w.document.createElement('div');
    newNode.setAttribute("Id", "chart_div");
    newNode.setAttribute("style", "width: 2000px; height: 1000px;");
    
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: I feel I am going wrong somewhere while creating a new node, still unable to catch the exact place where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the node from the wrong document. This solution is working:

```
    var w=window.open("");
    w.document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="chart"></div>';

    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(w.document.getElementById("chart"));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Comment: I tried using both of the below, however, the new html page does not display the content:
   var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(w.document.getElementById("chart_div"));
   var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(newNode);

Comment: You are correct, I have updated my response slightly.